# new locale not redirecting properly

Tags: django, django-templates, internationalization, django-cms

I have a basic django cms running with lots of localised content. I have been assigned to add few more languages before content can take over.

here is a sample english url:

```
<domain>/en/myhelp/
```

this is the sample menu which is supposed to render the menu dropdown:

```
<body>
    {% cms_toolbar %}
    <div class="container faq-main main-block">
        <div class="select-wrapper">
            <select name="language" id="faq-lang" class="lang-btn hide">
                <option value="en">English</option>
                <option value="hi">हिंदी</option>
                <option value="mr">मराठी</option>
                <option value="te">తెలుగు</option>
                <option value="ta">தமிழ்</option>
                <option value="kn">ಕನ್ನಡ</option>
                <option value="bn">বাংলা</option>
                <option value="ml">മലയാള൦</option>
                <option value="gu">ગુજરાતી</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
        {% block contact %}{% endblock contact %}
        {% block actions %}{% endblock actions %}
    </div>
    {% render_bundle 'faq' 'js' %}
    {% render_block "js" %}
</body>
```

any language selected from menu dropdown updates the url accordingly. for example on selecting `mr`, url mentioned above would change to:

```
<domain>/mr/myhelp/
```

All good so far.

Now i have added 2 more langs in this menu:

```
                <option value="od">ଓଡିଆ</option>
                <option value="as">অসমীয়া</option>
```

Problem is that when i select `od` / `as` from menu, url changes to:

```
<domain>/en/od/myhelp/
<domain>/en/as/myhelp/
```

basically, `en` is not removed from url locale causing `page not found` error. Any help or indication in right direction to correctly add this locale is appreciated.

version:

django-cms: 3.7.1 
Django: 2.1

basic code:

**urls.py**

```
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^events/(?P<path>.*)$', EventsProxyView.as_view()),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap,
        {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
    url(r'^healthcheck/$', healthcheck)
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^admin/login', home),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),  # NOQA
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)


urlpatterns += [
    url('', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
]
```

relevant part from settings.xml

```
import os  # isort:skip
from urllib.parse import urljoin

gettext = lambda s: s
DATA_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

import os
from django.conf import global_settings
import django.conf.locale

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '*', 
]



# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cms', 'templates'),],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.csrf',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'cms.context_processors.cms_settings',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ])],
        },
    },
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'redirection.middleware.MyHelpRedirectMiddleware',
    'djangocms_redirect.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.HostsPrinterMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.DisableCSRF',
    'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles/',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cms', 'scripts', 'dist', 'bundles', 'webpack-stats.json'),
    }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'treebeard',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'filer',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'djangocms_column',
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_snippet',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_video',
    'social_django',
    'revproxy',
    'djangocms_redirect',
    'redirection',
    'webpack_loader',
    'django_select2',
    'accordion'
]



LANGUAGES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('en', gettext('en')),
    ('hi', gettext('hi')),
    ('mr', gettext('mr')),
    ('te', gettext('te')),
    ('ta', gettext('ta')),
    ('kn', gettext('kn')),
    ('gu', gettext('gu')),
    ('bn', gettext('bn')),
    ('ml', gettext('ml')),
    ('as', gettext('as')),
    ('od', gettext('od'))
)

CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    ## Customize this
    1: [
        {
            'code': 'en',
            'name': gettext('en'),
            'redirect_on_fallback': True,
            'public': True,
            'hide_untranslated': False,
        },
        {
            'code': 'hi',
            'name': gettext('hi'),
            'public': True,
            'fallbacks': ['en'],
        },
        {
            'code': 'mr',
            'name': gettext('mr'),
            'public': True,
            'fallbacks': ['en'],
        },
         {
            'code': 'te',
            'name': gettext('te'),
            'public': True,
            'fallbacks': ['en'],
        },
         {
            'code': 'ta',
            'name': gettext('ta'),
            'public': True,
            'fallbacks': ['en'],
        },
        {
            'code': 'kn',
            'name': gettext('kn'),
            'public': True,
            'fallbacks': ['en'],
        },
         {
            'code': 'gu',
            'name': gettext('gu'),
            'public': True,
            'fallbacks': ['en'],
        },
        {
            'code': 'bn',
            'name': gettext('bn'),
            'public': True,
            'fallbacks': ['en'],
        },
         {
            'code': 'ml',
            'name': gettext('ml'),
            'public': True,
            'fallbacks': ['en'],
        },
        {
            'code': 'od',
            'name': gettext('od'),
            'public': True,
            'fallbacks': ['en'],
        },
        {
            'code': 'as',
            'name': gettext('as'),
            'public': True,
            'fallbacks': ['en'],
        }
    ],
    'default': {
        'fallbacks': ['en', 'hi'],
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        'public': True,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
    },
}

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('fullwidth.html', 'Fullwidth'),
    ('faq_fullwidth.html', 'FAQ Fullwidth'),
    ('faq_article.html', 'FAQ Article'),
    ('faq_article_with_feedback.html', 'FAQ Article with Feedback'),
)

CMS_PERMISSION = True

CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {}


MIGRATION_MODULES = {

}

THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.colorspace',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.autocrop',
    'filer.thumbnail_processors.scale_and_crop_with_subject_location',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.filters'
)

CMS_MYHELP_REDIRECT_USE_REQUEST = True
CMS_MYHELP_REDIRECT_ALLOWED_PATHS = {
    '/myhelp',
    '/myhelp/',
    '/en/myhelp',
    '/en/myhelp/',
    
}
```

Comment: We should also have the javascript which manages the redirection, no?

Comment: hello @Kureteiyu ... is there supposed to be one? i dont see any specific JS file in repo, there is one related to CKEditor. can you help me with where i can find it?

Comment: Oh I thought you were redirect by JS. I mean, if there is not, how/where is the redirection made?

Comment: Have you published any content in the languages that you're trying to access? The fact you're seeing the URL still showing `/en/` makes me think the system doesn't realise you're trying to get to a different language, so it's trying to load it as a path to a page.

Comment: @markwalker_ hello..i have not been able to publish because _publish url_ also has `en` prefixed and it starts throwing 404.

@Kureteiyu i thought it is being handled by django cms internally